# Spring CrudRepository findBy* method returning no results

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I've implemented a Repository extending `CrudRepository`. The underlying model (`Account`) has a `plaidAccountId` field and the corresponding query method is `findByPlaidAccountId`. Best I can tell, I have this wired up correctly as other queries on other models work correctly. However, this query returns no results. I've verified manually that items exist in the database that match the query param provided, yet still null is returned.

Below are the relevant configs. Let me know if there's anything else I can post that would be useful. Thanks in advance.

The query I'm executing:

`accountService.findByPlaidAccountId(account.getAccountId()`

I've logged to verify that `accountService` is initialized and `account.getAccount()` provides the expected string value.

```
// AccountRepository.java
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, Long> {

    Set<Account> findAllByUser(User user);
    Account findByPlaidAccountId(String plaidAccountId);
    Account findById(int id);
    Account findAccountByPlaidAccountId(String plaidAccountId);
}
```

--

```
// AccountService.java
@Service
public class AccountService {

    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Autowired
    public AccountService(AccountRepository repository) {
        this.accountRepository = repository;
    }

    public Account findById(int id) {
        return accountRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public Account findByPlaidAccountId(String plaidAccountId) {
        return accountRepository.findByPlaidAccountId(plaidAccountId);
    }

    public Iterable<Account> findAll() {
        return accountRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Set<Account> findAllByUser(User user) {
        return accountRepository.findAllByUser(user);
    }

    public void saveAccount(Account account) {
        accountRepository.save(account);
    }

    public Account findAccountByPlaidAccountId(String plaidAccountId) {
        return accountRepository.findAccountByPlaidAccountId(plaidAccountId);
    }
}
```

--

```
// Account.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "accounts")
public class Account {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "account_id")
private int id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private User user;

@Column(name = "plaid_account_id")
@NotEmpty(message = "Plaid account number is required")
private String plaidAccountId;

@Column(name = "account_type")
private String accountType;

@Column(name = "account_subtype")
private String accountSubtype;

@Column(name = "institution_id")
private String institutionId;

@Column(name = "current_balance")
private double currentBalance;

@Column(name = "available_balance")
private double availableBalance;

@Column(name = "account_limit")
private double accountLimit;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "official_name")
private String officialName;

@Column(name = "mask")
private String mask;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "plaid_item_id", nullable = false)
private PlaidItem plaidItem;

public Account() {
}
// ... getters and setters
```

**Update: JPA SQL logging**

```
Hibernate: select account0_.account_id as account_1_0_, account0_.account_limit as account_2_0_, account0_.account_subtype as account_3_0_, account0_.account_type as account_4_0_, account0_.available_balance as availabl5_0_, account0_.current_balance as current_6_0_, account0_.institution_id as institut7_0_, account0_.mask as mask8_0_, account0_.name as name9_0_, account0_.official_name as officia10_0_, account0_.plaid_account_id as plaid_a11_0_, account0_.plaid_item_id as plaid_i12_0_, account0_.user_id as user_id13_0_ from accounts account0_ where account0_.plaid_account_id=?
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161619/discussion-on-question-by-justinraczak-spring-crudrepository-findby-method-retu).

Answer (score 4):

I see in your code some things that could generate a future problem, I dont know if they are the ones giving you the headace but gonna give you one in the future.

```
// AccountRepository.java 
 @Repository 
 public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, Long> {        
    Set<Account> findAllByUser(User user);        
    Account findByPlaidAccountId(String plaidAccountId);      
    Account findById(int id);        
    Account findByPlaidAccountId(String plaidAccountId); 
 }
```

The first thing is "`CrudRepository<Account, Long>`" you have Long here but the ID of your class is "int", they should be the same.

```
Account findByPlaidAccountId(String plaidAccountId);
Account findAccountByPlaidAccountId(String plaidAccountId);
```

Those two methods expect a single Account object in return, but plaidAccountId is not unique or pk, so you have to expect a list. 
If you are sure that there is only one element and don't one to handle a list on your aplication just change the Repository to `Set/List<Account>` and the Service keep it like this:

```
public Account findByPlaidAccountId(String plaidAccountId) {
        return accountRepository.findByPlaidAccountId(plaidAccountId).get(0);
}
```

or

```
findFirstByPlaidAccountId
```

Good luck with that null return ;).

Comment: I cant accept this answer because it doesn't solve the problem from the question, but I really appreciate these tips! These things are super helpful to understand as I learn the framework. Question about the value of the ID in the CrudRepository extension: I use primitive int value in my model but the repository instantiation won't take primitives. Will it behave the same if I pass `Integer` there?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, my values had been saved to the databased *including* their quotation marks, so the correct query was technically `"<value>"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you search by `plaidAccountId` (how your method is called) I suppose you want to pass that id instead of `account.getAccountId()`

```
accountService.findByPlaidAccountId(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this is just disparity between domain models. Externally, from the API, the target value is returned as `accountId`. Because I have internal account IDs in my app, I add the namespace `plaid`, so the _external_ value of `accountId` is mapped to the _internal_ value of `plaidAccountId`. These two values are mapped to each, so the result of `getAccountId()` is the correct value to pass in.